# Is it recommended practice to include extension method within the static class itself?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I have:

```
public static class DataManager
{
    private static Dictionary<string, DataTable> dataTables;

    //    extension method
    public static DataTable GetTable ( this string TableName )
    {
        return dataTables[ TableName ];
    }

}
```

I didn't want to expose the Dictionary collection, and this is the way I thought to accomplish this task. In my calling method:

```
DataTable GetTable (string TableName)
{
    return TableName.GetTable();
}
```

Is there another way I should, or could do this? Or is this acceptable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think that this is a good idea because, your method does *not* operate on a `string` (what the extension method would state), it operates on `DataManager`. So just use a static method in this case.

Comment: I think the word `work` should be in italics, not `not`  :)  Perhaps `operate` would be a better choice here.

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, as it's written it *would* work on a string (`"foo".GetTable()`), but that seems like a rather unintuitive (and annoying) calling convention.

Comment: I disagree. I have implemented this and I get a return DataTable object with the data loaded.

Comment: @IAbstract: yes as mentioned by Adam, this *works*, but it is unintuitive.

Comment: Unintuitive because no one has thought about using an extension method this way? How many people felt that Linq was unintuitive when we first looked at that? Saying something is unintuitive is a weak response. Is there a good explanation as to *why* this is a bad practice?

Comment: @IAbstract: No, it would be unintuitive because noone would expect to find your method available on a `string` object, not even with IntelliSense. Your method needs a string argument but doesn't "focus" on it. Would the following make sense? `string connString = "..."; IDbConnection conn = connString.CreateConnection();` -- Another problem you'd be facing: What if your method has >1 parameter? Which one will be the type on which you're basing the extension method? It'll quickly get arbitrary; because there's no good reason why you should use an extension method in this way in the first place!

Comment: @IAbstract (cont'd): Another thing to consider is, imagine how crowded IntelliSense will get when you extend `string` with lots of different methods just because they need a string parameter. You'll have ADO.NET methods, WCF methods, XML methods, COM interop methods all thrown in. IntelliSense becomes useless. Contrast this with how it actually should be: IntelliSense shows you methods on a `string` object that also act on a string.

Comment: @IAbstract: Plenty of people have thought of using extension methods in this way, but it's (IMO) an abuse of extension methods. As @stakx points out, you just have a function that takes a `string` parameter. You're not doing anything to the string itself, it's just an argument. You aren't turning the string into a table, you're looking up a table with the same name.

Comment: @IAbstract: Additionally, I don't believe that "it's unintuitive" is a weak answer at all. You're designing an API, and API's should--when possible and practical--be intuitive. If you knew nothing about this library, would you *really* think to write `"TableName".GetTable()` rather than `DataManager.GetTable("TableName")`? Even if LINQ is unintuitive (which I don't find it to be, but I'll grant for the purposes of discussion), it adds *value*. It lets you do things in a much simpler manner than was possible before. This paradigm, however, does not add value.

Comment: @Adam: *This paradigm, however, does not add value,* this argument wins. I can agree that it doesn't add any value and I will change the method. :)